# angularui navbar dropdown issues in v1.3.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am new to angularui and I am trying to create an menu with dropdown.

I have seen an example that works with 0.6.0 version of angularui and angularjs 1.1.5 the dropdown menus work

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true"
                ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

full example in http://plnkr.co/edit/HkwfL9

However, when I change the dependencies, to angularjs 1.5.5 and angularui 1.3.3 the view is as expected but the dropdowns do not work (http://plnkr.co/edit/rNaNj8gqnrwOwOVnGlD2)

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Thanks a million!

Comment: You are not using the ui-bootstrap directives, try this http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#dropdown

Comment: I have updated http://plnkr.co/edit/rNaNj8gqnrwOwOVnGlD2 using uib-dropdown and it is now working for me. Thanks for the push in the right direction @AluanHaddad.